# How to combine nested lists based on their index?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Consider these nested lists:

```
L1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
L2 = [[11,22,33],[44,55,66]]
L3 = [[111,222,333],[444,555,666],[777,888,999]]
L4 = [12,13,14] # Note: not a nested list
```

I require:

```
output1 = [1,4,7,11,44,111,444,777,12]
output2 = [2,5,8,22,55,222,555,888,13]
output3 = [3,6,9,33,66,333,666,999,14]
```

Comment: answer requires your attempts

Comment: you should show us what you've tried before asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
L = L1+L2+L3+[L4]
output1 = [l[0] for l in L]
output2 = [l[1] for l in L]
output3 = [l[2] for l in L]
```

Answer (score 3):

A oneliner:

```
output1, output2, output3 = [[l[i] for l in L1+L2+L3+[L4]] for i in range(3)]
```

Outputs:

```
>>> output1
[1, 4, 7, 11, 44, 111, 444, 777, 12]
>>> output2
[2, 5, 8, 22, 55, 222, 555, 888, 13]
>>> output3
[3, 6, 9, 33, 66, 333, 666, 999, 14]
```

Though you really should provide a sample of what you tried when asking for a solution :-)

#### Update

As we are apparently indulging ourselves with a friendly competition, here's the timing of different answers on my machine (python3):

**Code:**

```
import time

L1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
L2 = [[11,22,33],[44,55,66]]
L3 = [[111,222,333],[444,555,666],[777,888,999]]
L4 = [12,13,14]


t = time.process_time()

output1, output2, output3 = [[l[i] for l in L1+L2+L3+[L4]] for i in range(3)]

print(output1)
print(output2)
print(output3)

print("%.7f" %(time.process_time() - t))


t = time.process_time()

output1, output2, output3 = map(list,(zip(*L1+L2+L3+[L4])))

print(output1)
print(output2)
print(output3)

print("%.7f" %(time.process_time() - t))


t = time.process_time()

from itertools import chain

output_1, output_2, output_3 = zip(*chain(L1, L2, L3, [L4]))

print(output1)
print(output2)
print(output3)

print("%.7f" %(time.process_time() - t))
```

**Results** (of one of the fastest runs):

```
[1, 4, 7, 11, 44, 111, 444, 777, 12]
[2, 5, 8, 22, 55, 222, 555, 888, 13]
[3, 6, 9, 33, 66, 333, 666, 999, 14]
0.0000650
[1, 4, 7, 11, 44, 111, 444, 777, 12]
[2, 5, 8, 22, 55, 222, 555, 888, 13]
[3, 6, 9, 33, 66, 333, 666, 999, 14]
0.0000356
[1, 4, 7, 11, 44, 111, 444, 777, 12]
[2, 5, 8, 22, 55, 222, 555, 888, 13]
[3, 6, 9, 33, 66, 333, 666, 999, 14]
0.0002259
```

@Chris_Rands answer seems to be the fastest :-)

Comment: short and quick solution +1. Though, it would be enough to do it with `... for l in L1+L2+L3+[L4]]...`

Comment: Thanks, missed that. Edited my answer to reflect your great suggestion :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple solution with `zip`:

```
output1, output2, output3 = map(list,(zip(*L1+L2+L3+[L4])))
```

Note that if you are content with tuples instead of lists, this can be further simplified:

```
output1, output2, output3 = zip(*L1+L2+L3+[L4])
```

I found this to be slightly faster than using `chain` to merge the lists, at least for this data. It also appears to be faster than @Gormador's solution.

```
>>> def f1():
...     output1, output2, output3 = zip(*L1+L2+L3+[L4])
... 
>>> def f2():
...     output_1, output_2, output_3 = zip(*chain(L1, L2, L3, [L4]))
... 
>>> def f3():
...     output1, output2, output3 = [[l[i] for l in L1+L2+L3+[L4]] for i in range(3)]
... 
>>> timeit(lambda: f1(), number = 1000000)
1.5090796248987317
>>> timeit(lambda: f2(), number = 1000000)
1.7326991918962449
>>> timeit(lambda: f3(), number = 1000000)
5.100052359048277
```

Answer (score 1):

I am amazed that no one has mentioned the usage of [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) with [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip). The simplest solution will be:

```
from itertools import chain

output_1, output_2, output_3 = zip(*chain(L1, L2, L3, [L4]))
```

which make variables hold the value as:

```
>>> output_1
(1, 4, 7, 11, 44, 111, 444, 777, 12)
>>> output_2
(2, 5, 8, 22, 55, 222, 555, 888, 13)
>>> output_3
(3, 6, 9, 33, 66, 333, 666, 999, 14)
```

Comment: As I show in my solution, you don't need the `chain`, just add the lists

Comment: @Chris_Rands : If you will measure the execution time of all the solution including yours; you will see how it is better

Comment: Adding lists creates a new list adding extra overhead whereas `chain` generates a `iterator`

Comment: I just added some timings to my answer, I find using `chain` is slightly slower, at least for this data

Comment: Your solution is four times slower than mine apparently.

Comment: @Gormador Really? I could not replicate that in my answer

Comment: @Chris_Rands: You are right. I verified it. For small data `chain` is slower and I verified that in this case it is taking 0.4 micro seconds more. But I do not agree with you @Gormador. Your solution is taking around 5 mirco seconds whereas Chris's and mine's take 1.5 and 1.9 respectively

Comment: I took the time to load the package into account ;-) Petty, I know, but also real world :-D Also, the "four times slower" was on a single run. I amended my answer :-)